# How to display recently compared products in the products page in magento?

Tags: magento

I displayed both the "compare products" and "Recently Viewed Products" but unable to display "Recently Compared Products".

How can i do this..can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

I have not try this code but hope it will help you.

```
$items = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_compare_item_collection')
            ->useProductItem(true)
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $items->setCustomerId(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId());
        }
        else {
            $items->setVisitorId(Mage::getSingleton('log/visitor')->getId());
        }
```

Comment: hey mufaddal, where should i put this..?

Comment: in phtml file where you put your code for displaying recently compared products